# Derived category of product of complex manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, derived-categories

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a compact complex manifold. Is it possible to describe the derived category $D^b(X\times Y)$ of coherent sheaves in terms of $D^b(X)$ and $D^b(Y)$? I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are both curves, or where $X$ is a surface and $Y$ is a curve.

Comment: You can think about $D^b(X\times Y)$ as about the category of functors $D^b(X) \to D^b(Y)$ (an object on the product corresponds to Fourier--Mukai transform).

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.0157, maybe? Or if you want to be singular, http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7164?

Comment: Bad things happen if you don't assume that your varieties are algebraic (Moishezon).